# Use threading python socket client that listens in the background and can send real time messages

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, sockets, queue, client

**What I’m Trying to Do:**
I’m trying to create a client script that can listen for potential messages from the server and receive input from a user at any point that tells the script to send a message to the server all on a single socket. The server I’m working with will only connect to one client at a time, so everything is on one socket. 
The script will facilitate interaction between a maya ui and a file with prewritten functions that determine what to send to the server.

**How it works:**
I have the script with two threads. The parent thread is the adding messages thread and there is a child thread that runs the listening in the background. The child thread has a constant background loop, listening for any messages from the server (for example an error message) and reads a message queue to see if anything has been added. If something is added to the queue, the listening loop stops, sends a message, then starts the listening loop again. The parent thread allows the user to add a command into the message queue using the add_message() attribute. The maya ui will have buttons that call functions to add commands to the message queue. I made this with python 2.7

Here is an simplified example of the client. I added a single message before starting the listening loop so you can see what it is supposed to look like.

```
import socket
import struct
import threading
import Queue
import time

class ThreadedClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #set up queues
        self.send_q = Queue.Queue(maxsize = 10)
        #declare instance variables       
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        #connect to socket
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))

    #LISTEN
    def listen(self):
        while True: #loop forever
            try:
                print 'checking for message...'
                # stops listening if there's a message to send
                if self.send_q.empty() == False:
                    self.send_message()
                else:
                    print 'no message'
                print 'listening...'
                message = self.s.recv(4096)
                print 'RECEIVED: ' + message
            except socket.timeout:
                pass

    def start_listen(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.listen())
        t.start()
        #t.join()
        print 'started listen'


    #ADD MESSAGE
    def add_message(self, msg):
        #put message into the send queue
        self.send_q.put(msg)
        print 'ADDED MSG: ' + msg
        #self.send_message()

    #SEND MESSAGE
    def send_message(self):
        #send message
        msg = self.get_send_q()
        if msg == "empty!":
            print "nothing to send"
        else:
            self.s.sendall(msg)
            print 'SENDING: ' + msg
            #restart the listening
            #self.start_listen()


    #SAFE QUEUE READING
    #if nothing in q, prints "empty" instead of stalling program
    def get_send_q(self):       
        if self.send_q.empty():
            print "empty!"
            return "empty!"
        else:
            msg = self.send_q.get()
            return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 8001
    address = 'localhost'
    s = ThreadedClient(address, port)
    s.start()
    print('Server started, port: ', port)

    s.add_message('hello world')
    s.start_listen()
    s.add_message('hello world')
```

And here is an example server for the client:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 8001)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

**Problem:**
Once I start the listening loop thread, the script will no longer take any more input. Just as a test I added a line after starting the listening thread that would add a message to the queue and nothing happens.

**Previous Approaches:**
This question is essentially exactly what I’m trying to do as well, although it was never solved: [How to handle chat client using threading and queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297296/how-to-handle-chat-client-using-threading-and-queues)

I have looked at [Grab user input asynchronously and pass to an Event loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941851/grab-user-input-asynchronously-and-pass-to-an-event-loop-in-python) about creating a main loop that accepts user input and have tried implementing the queue system but am getting stuck.

I’ve also tried out [How to use threading to get user input realtime while main still running in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768865/how-to-use-threading-to-get-user-input-realtime-while-main-still-running-in-pyth) approach but I can’t use `raw_input()` for my final usage of the code. I have also tried socket.timeout, but also loops without taking input.

One approach I was considering was making the script asynchronous, but from what I’ve read I don’t think it will resolve the issue.

**TL/DR:**
Is there a way to create a script that has a client listening to the server loop running in the background while at the same time being able to accept real time commands from the user?

I would greatly appreciate any help or nudge in the right direction, I've been stuck on this a while now.

Comment: This is a very confused structure. You call the constructor of `ThreadedClient` (which is a subclass of `threading.Thread`) but you don't provide either a `run` method or `target` argument, so when you call `.start()` it, it immediately exits. Then later you call `start_listen` method on the object from your main thread, which actually creates *a second* thread with a `target` set to the object's `listen` method. It would have made more sense to have the constructor provide `target=self.listen` when it invoked the super-class constructor. Then you wouldn't need `start_listen`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'm new to python and threads so I'm not as familiar with the way things should be structured. I called `start_listen()` in the `__init__()` and it works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The script works. There were just some errors throwing it off. In the `start_listen()` function

```
 t = threading.Thread(target = self.listen())
```

should be

```
 t = threading.Thread(target = self.listen)
```

and then in the `__init__()` after

```
self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))
```

add

```
self.s.settimeout(.1)
```

so that the script will cycle through the while loop.